# Ultimos Registros de una Base de Datos en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando traer los ultimos 10 registros de mi base de datos la cual estoy usando con MySQL y cada vez que se carguen traer los siguientes 10, me explico, tengo 50 registros de los cuales quiero traer solamente los ultimos 10 en este caso serian del 40 al 50 pero cuando se carguen quiero traer los siguientes 10 ultimos que serian del 30 al 40 y asi sucesivamente, tengo esta sentencia sql

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY id DESC limit 10
```

que me permite traer los ultimos 10(40-50) pero como puedo traer los siguientes 10(30-40) o existe alguna sentencia o alguna manera de trear los siguientes 10 y asi sucesivamente hasta llegar al primer registro?

Comment: Prueba con `LIMIT 10,10` y `LIMIT 20,10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos puedes usar [LIMIT MYSQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) combinando con [Offset Mysql](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html)

teniendo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `songs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(1, 'Paradise City');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(2, 'Get in the Ring');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(3, 'Night Train');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(4, 'Sweet Child O'' Mine');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(5, 'Welcome to the Jungle');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(6, 'Pretty Tied Up');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(7, 'November Rain');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(8, 'Patience');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(9, 'Mr. Brownstone');
INSERT INTO `songs` VALUES(10, 'Rocket Queen');
```

Se desea hacer una paginación de 3 en 3 los registros entonces con el uso de **limit** y **offset** los 3 primeros los obtengo asi:

```
> SELECT id, title from songs LIMIT 0, 3;
1 Paradise City
2 Get in the Ring
3 Night Train
```

Como vemos me obtiene los 3 efectivamente ahora los siguientes 3:

```
> SELECT id, title from songs LIMIT 3, 3;
4 Sweet Child O' Mine
5 Welcome to the Jungle
6 Pretty Tied Up
```

Como vemos de esta manera muy facil podemos obtener los registros en el orden deseado y paginación deseada, finalmente los 3 siguientes:

```
> SELECT id, title from songs LIMIT 6, 3;
7 November Rain
8 Patience
9 Mr. Brownstone
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias era exactamente lo que estaba buscando